# Testing an endpoint with a primitive variable and an object as method parameters in Postman

Tags: c#, json, postman

I have written an endpoint in C# which takes a primitive variable and an object.  I want to test this endpoint by passing the Id, along with an object that contains properties that can be used to filter a query and return the result that the user is looking for.  The problem that I am facing is that, I cannot figure out how to pass both the Id and object at the same time in Postman so that I can test the endpoint.

I have tried to pass the courseId as regular parameter, along with the object in the body, but it doesn't work.  I also tried to pass both in the body and at the same time put the `[FromBody]` before the datatype of courseId, it also didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Here is the method in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<CourseDAO> Courses(long? courseId, [FromBody]CourseFilter paramsObject)
{
    //Create an instance of the CourseService class
    CourseService course = new CourseService();

    //Return the result of the GetAllCourses method in the  CourseService class
    return course.Courses(courseId, paramsObject);
}
```

Inside the object are properties such as Active (bool), Deleted (bool), etc. These two properties for example are used to determine whether a course is offered/temporarily not offered in the case of Active or permanently not offered in the case of Deleted.

Comment: You can't POST a body to a `HttpGet` method. Change it to `HttpPost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint is correct parameter-wise, you're just using the wrong HTTP verb.

[`HttpGet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.httpgetattribute) only allows you to supply a query string to the method.

In order to post a body, you need to use [`HttpPost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.httppostattribute):

```
[HttpPost]
public List<CourseDAO> Courses(long? courseId, [FromBody] CourseFilter paramsObject)
{
   // ...
}
```

You should now be able to correctly access your endpoint using Postman:

[image]

Learn more about routing and HTTP verbs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing).

Comment: Oh ok.  Thanks that worked.  I can now pass the object and the Id at the same time.