# Endpoint receives object with wrong values

Tags: c#, json, rest

I have an endpoint written in C# that is supposed to receive an object as a parameter of the function.  The object, for testing purposes, only has two properties: Active and Deleted.  When I set the object in Postman in order to test the endpoint with Active having a value of true and Deleted having a value of false or vice versa, the values are ignored and the endpoint returns the object with the value of both properties set to false.

Here is the method in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public dynamic Courses(long? courseId, CourseFilter paramsObject)
{
    //Create an instance of the CourseService class
    CourseService course = new CourseService();

    //Return the result of the GetAllCourses method in the CourseService class
    //return course.Courses(courseId, paramsObject);
    return ("Active: " + paramsObject.Active + " " + "Deleted: " + paramsObject.Deleted);

    return paramsObject;
}
```

Please note that I am just using `dynamic` and returning the object just for testing and debugging purposes to see if the values are correct.

Here is the picture of the object in Postman:

[HttpPost JSON Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCnX8.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you're posting with Postman doesn't seem to be correct.
The data structure you're currently posting would be equal to this in C#:

```
class Root
{
    public ParamsObject ParamsObject { get; set; }
}

class ParamsObject
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

But it seems like you just want to post a `ParamsObject` object and not something of type `Root`.

Try modifying your JSON in Postman to this:

```
{
  "Active": true,
  "Deleted": false
}
```

*Unrelated to the question:*

This is the [second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56940206/testing-an-endpoint-with-a-primitive-variable-and-an-object-as-method-parameters) you're posting a beginner level ASP.NET question in the span of an hour. You can even see how you would correctly post this object in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV0sr.png) of my previous answer!

I would recommend you research these things before posting as there is plenty of learning material out there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  I have tried looking up things up before posting it on here.  Trust me, I am not interested in re-posting questions which have been answered or wasting yours or any other users' time.  I only posted these two questions when I reached a dead end on both trying different ways to figure it out on my own and through looking things up.

Comment: If you really did research and reached a dead end, I guess it's okay! Did my answer at least solve your problem?

Comment: Not sure why the question would be down voted, but yes it did.  Thanks.